# Having issues with using libraries and CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.0.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Anthony\.clion10\system\cmake\generated\d04e461a\d04e461a\Debug --target all -- -j 8
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_library):
See also "C:/Users/Anthony/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/d04e461a/d04e461a/Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  add_library cannot create target "Majick" because another target with the
  same name already exists.  The existing target is an executable created in
  source directory "C:/Users/Anthony/ClionProjects/Majick".  See
  documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.

Makefile:163: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

I'm having lots of problems doing this, and I'm at fault. I don't understand this at all. Being used to convenient linking has killed me, I guess. This is what I have.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(Majick)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

#add_subdirectory(C:/Users/Anthony/ClionProjects/glfw Majick/glfw)
#add_subdirectory(C:/Users/Anthony/ClionProjects/glm Majick/glm)
#add_subdirectory(C:/Users/Anthony/ClionProjects/glew Majick/glew)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(Majick ${SOURCE_FILES})

include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(C:/Users/Anthony/ClionProjects/glew/lib/Release/x64 C:/Users/Anthony/ClionProjects/glfw/lib-mingw)
target_link_libraries(Majick ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} glfw3 glew32s opengl32)

add_library(Majick STATIC)
```

This makes me feel stupid, but I have no idea what's going on. I've spent the last five hours or so googling to no avail. Does anyone mind helping me solve my problem and maybe providing some place I can get more information on CMake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: There are two targets with the same name which is not possible in CMake.

```
add_executable(Majick ${SOURCE_FILES})
...
add_library(Majick STATIC)
```

I guess the second target just needs to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks, that resolved that problem. I hate to ask you to fix more problems, but now that that's out of the way I'm getting [this error with this code](http://pastebin.com/A1HXWrtA)